# How to escape PyMySQL select for LIKE %keyword or keyword% condition

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, pymysql

I'm looking to execute a request using pymysql for python 2.7 and I would separate request and parameter to automatically escape character and for more security.

I cannot figure out how to do it for a request like this:

```
req = "SELECT * FROM \`{table}` WHERE {key1} LIKE '%{keyword1}'  OR
{key2} LIKE '{keyword2}%' OR {key3} LIKE
'%{keyword3}%'".format(table=table, key1=key, keyword1=keyword,
key2=key, keyword2=keyword, key3=key, keyword3=keyword);
```

Do anyone know how to do ?